# mysql: Multiple records into one?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table:

```
userChoice
 - userId
 - choiceId
```

This table contains two foreign key columns. `userId` is 1 to many, so i'll have many records of one user for each choice. Is there a way to return one record with with many `choiceId`?

Comment: Yes, this is User record.

Comment: You MUST give names in the snake_case notation to any DB entries!!!!

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. What does "one record with with many `choiceId`" mean, *exactly*? Also 'userId is 1 to many' doesn't make sense. Maybe you mean that binary relation userChoice(userId, choiceId) is 1:many. Also 'many records of one user for each choice' doesn't make sense. Maybe you mean 'many records for one user'. Please also read & act on [mcve]--give example input & output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) should fit the bill:

```
SELECT   user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(choice_id)
FROM     userChoice
GROUP BY user_id
```

**EDIT:**
To answer the question in the comment - yes, you could also add a `where` clause to this query. E.g.:

```
SELECT   user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(choice_id)
FROM     userChoice
WHERE    user_id  = 2
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: can i add a where clause to that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use group_concat and grouop by userId

```
 select userId, group_concat(choiceId)
 from userChoice
 group by userId
```